# Formatting date in find() mongoDB/mongoose query result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, format, handlebars.js, isodate

My MongoDB collection have an ISODate field and I want to format the result to dd/mm/yyyy.

My model:

```
const Pedido = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cliente: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'clientes',
        required: true 
    },
    date: {
        type:Date
    }
})
mongoose.model('pedidos',Pedido)
```

And that's the query and render:

```
var query = await Pedido.find().populate('cliente').lean().exec()
res.render("admin/pedidos",{pedidos: query})
```

I'm using **handlebars**

```
{{#each pedidos}}
<h5 class="ordem1">Pedido #{{id}} <small>{{date}}</small></h5>
{{/each}}
```

It's showing a result like that:

**Wed Apr 08 2020 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (GMT-03:00)**

but I want to show: **08/04/2020**

Could anybody help me with this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can use `$dateToString` operator to format date, check the [mongoDb Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)

as you can see, we can use this `$dateToString` operator only in aggregate pipeline, in the $project step

here is a simple example in mongo playground [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YyHYBI3QoXh)

in your example, we could do the same process, but use `$lookup` instead of `populate`

the query may be something like that

```
Pedido.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {} // add your search here
    },
    {
        $lookup: { // this is the alternative to the populate
            from: 'clientes',
            localField: 'cliente',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'clientes'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: { // add all the fields you need from the collection, if you need to omit something from the query results, just don't mention it here
            id: 1,
            clientes: 1,
            date: { $dateToString: { format: "%d/%m/%Y", date: "$date" } } // this will return the date in the format "dd/MM/yyyy"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!